# Unable to rewrite url in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am unable to rewrite the request url below is how my next.config looks

```js
module.exports = withPlugins([
...
  {
    async rewrites() {
      console.log("Rewrites called");
      console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOCS_URL)
      return [
        {
          source: '/docs',
          destination: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOCS_URL,
        }
        
      ]
    }
```

console logs are correctly printed with new urls but the component is not getting updated with correct links :

```js
 <Link href="/docs">
     <Button className={NavbarClasses.button}>
         <Box color={navWhite ? 'black' : 'white'}>Docs</Box>
      </Button>
  </Link>
```

The contents of .env file is as below:
`NEXT_PUBLIC_DOCS_URL = http://localhost:4000/docs/intro`

But the Link is rendered as localhost:3000 instead of *localhost:4000*.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure - your expected outcome is to see `http://localhost:4000/docs` in your address bar after clicking the link?

Comment: yes want the rendered url to look like http://localhost:4000/docs. I did as it's mentioned in https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/apps/www/next.config.js , but somehow it's not reflecting

Comment: `rewrites` doesn't work that way, you'll see `localhost:3000/docs` in the address bar but the contents of the page will be whatever you're rewriting to.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites):

> Rewrites act as a URL proxy and mask the destination path, making it
> appear the user hasn't changed their location on the site. In
> contrast, redirects will reroute to a new page and show the URL
> changes.

In the nutshell, when user opens your `/docs` page on `localhost:3000` Next.js will send a request on his behalf to `localhost:4000` and pass back response. From user's perspective, it looks like `localhost:3000` is producing it.

If it's crucial for you to retain original URL, you should use [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects).

> Redirects allow you to redirect an incoming request path to a
> different destination path.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I realized both rewirtes and redirects work only when page is manually refreshed. So when I click on docs it goes to localhost:3000/docs then on manually page refresh it updates to localhost:4000/docs

Comment: @Bhupendra _"both rewirtes and redirects work only when page is manually refreshed"_ - that's not entirely correct. That is the case for `redirects` but not for `rewrites` - `rewrites` are also applied on client-side navigations when using `next/router` or `next/link`.